# Writing without clearing the entire screen

Tags: abap

I want to write something after a user command in **report programming**. (when he pushes a button in pf-status). But I dont want the screen to be cleared. It's like I want to append text in the end of a line **without refreshing the page**. Because it will take long if I want to refresh the page.

```
CASE: sy-ucomm.
  WHEN: 'MALF'.
    WRITE : icon_okay AS ICON. (APPEND TO AND OF A ANY LINE)
ENDCASE.
```

So, Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [`MODIFY LINE`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPMODIFY_LINE.htm). There's a sample program named `DEMO_LIST_MODIFY_FIELD_VALUE` available.

(EDIT, obvious rant: ...or start using an up-to-date UI technology altogether :-))